# An error message of compiling, GMP, Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, gmp

I am installing a library, and got an error message after `make`:

```
gcc -Wcast-qual -Wswitch -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-unused -std=c99  -U__STRICT_ANSI__ -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -I../mlgmpidl -I../apron -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/ocaml -I/usr/local/lib/ocaml -c -o scalar_caml_debug.o scalar_caml.c
In file included from scalar_caml.c:23:0:
../mlgmpidl/gmp_caml.h: In function ‘camlidl_mpfr_rnd_t_c2ml’:
../mlgmpidl/gmp_caml.h:49:3: error: ‘GMP_RND_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../mlgmpidl/gmp_caml.h:49:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
../mlgmpidl/gmp_caml.h: In function ‘camlidl_mpfr_rnd_t_ml2c’:
../mlgmpidl/gmp_caml.h:52:24: error: ‘GMP_RND_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [scalar_caml_debug.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone know what happened? Maybe it is related to the versioni of GMP, does anyone know how to check it? Thank you very much

**Edit1:** `ldconfig -p | grep gmp` returns

```
libgmpxx.so.4 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so.4
libgmpxx.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so
libgmp.so.3 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so.3
libgmp.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgmp.so
```

`/usr/local/include/` contains: `gmp.h  mpf2mpfr.h  mpfr.h`, and `/usr/local/lib/` contains
`alt-ergo  libgmp.a   libgmp.so     libgmp.so.10.0.2  libmpfr.la  libmpfr.so.4      ocaml      python2.7
coq       libgmp.la  libgmp.so.10  libmpfr.a         libmpfr.so  libmpfr.so.4.0.1  python2.6  site_ruby`

Could anyone tell me which version of GMP has been installed on my machine?

Comment: `ldconfig -p` can be used to determine the version of libraries --I am assuming you're on Linux. I'm unsure about the equivalent in OSX, but I'm sure there are synonym guides out there for OSX and linux now that you know a possible command.

Comment: @nlucaroni, thanks for your help... I am using Linux, I have edited my initial post, could you please help?

Comment: Where did you get `mlgmpidl`? What version is that? I don't see anything about `GMP_RND_MAX` in `gmp_caml.h` from the source I found online.

Comment: Actually I did not download the right version of `mlgmpidl`...

Answer (score 3):

Your version of libgmp-dev is probably older than the version of mlgmpidl you are using, which explains that mlgmpidl asks for things that are not defined.